Appending/Adding new Formio Templates on button click
I've a problem in my current set up.
I'm using a formio JSON template for the FE and grabbing the form data via the JS.
Now what I want to do is to be able to dynamically append or add more Templates onto a existing one at the Click of the button.
I've an example below I'd need to be able to add a new "Entity" template on clicking a button beside the radio buttons in arounds that (design not final).
Then for each input name of the Entity I want the Tab name to be updated.

Is this feasible in formio?
